# "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized"

Tags: linux, virtualbox, wireshark, qt

I have created a Kali-Linux environment on Windows using Oracle VM VirtualBox 6.1.32. I've been trying to run wireshark on kali-linux. But when I type wireshark in the terminal, I get this error. I've looked for questions similar to this one on superuser, but couldn't find a detailed answer. How can I solve this?

```
 ** (wireshark:19687) 14:17:31.443363 [GUI WARNING] -- could not connect to display 
 ** (wireshark:19687) 14:17:31.444951 [GUI ERROR] -- This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```

Comment: Wireshark is a GUI application. Are you running a GUI?

Comment: How can I run the GUI?